# If $f(n) = O(g(n))$ and $f(n) \not\in o(g(n))$, does $f(n) = \Theta(g(n))$?

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics

If $f(n) = O(g(n))$ and $f(n) \not\in o(g(n))$, does $f(n) = \Theta(g(n))$?

From the assumptions, $g(n)$ seems to be an asymptotic tight upper bound for $f(n)$, but do they make $g(n)$ an asymptotic tight lower bound for $f(n)$ as well?

Comment: No of cource. just follow  definitions

Comment: [Please read this to learn how to properly format your questions.](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f(n) = O(g(n))$ means that $|f(n)| \leq C |g(n)|$, but $f(n) \not\in o(g(n))$ means that you can't make the $C$ as small as you want. If $f(n) = \Theta(g(n))$, it would mean that $|g(n)| \leq D |f(n)|$ for some other bound. What happens if you try $g(n) = 1$ and $f(n) = 0$ if $n$ is even, $f(n) = 1$ if $n$ is odd?

Comment: @yi416 Where intuition come from but this might be the case? This example might look a little weird but conflicting examples like this is extremely straightforward simply from looking at the definition of the relevant terms. If this result surprises you should probably spend a lot more time practicing with big-o and little-o

Comment: I’m sorry if that comes across as rude or condescending. I’m seriously asking what your intuition is about this because I don’t really see any reason to not find this result intuitive.